# Empty URI query string parameters: "a=&b=" versus "a&b"

Tags: http, url

Should the following URLs be considered functionally equivalent?

```
http://example.com/foo?a=&b=

http://example.com/foo?a&b
```

This came about when a user of a Drupal module I wrote which parses apart and then rewrites URIs [noticed](http://drupal.org/node/348421#comment-5759210) that the code sometimes causes the query string parts to change in unexpected ways due to how some of the underlying PHP functions behave. For example:

```php
parse_str("a&b", $values); print http_build_query($values);

a=&b=
```

Is this something I should bother worrying about?

Edit so SO stops complaining that this question is similar to another one: The question is whether it's safe to assume that "no value for X" and "empty value for X" are equivalent, not whether the "no value" style is syntactically correct (which it is).

Comment: as an opinion, yes, this is something you should worry about since this will sooner or later break in mysterious ways that can be hard to debug, depending on how you plan to consume a and b query parameters. If they are going to be empty/null, why generate them in the first place? a better approach might be for the server script to check for existence of these params

Comment: I really don't have control what any of the servers being linked to are going to do. I'm basically just hoping that there's a codified standard out there that I couldn't find that someone can point me to, or, failing that, just a widely consistent method of implementation. If I can't find either, then I might have to start worrying and reinventing wheels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RFC 3986 Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-23) doesn't have anything to say about the structure of the query string aside from how characters like `?` should be dealt with. So strictly speaking, your two example URLs *are* different. Of course, the application which receives those query strings may treat them as functionally equivalent, but this isn't something you can determine from the URL alone.

Answer (score -1):

As per [RFC6570](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570) empty query parameters are allowed. Please refer to section 3.2.9

```
   Example Template     Expansion

   {&x,y,empty}       &x=1024&y=768&empty=
```

Comment: That's the RFC for URI Templates, rather than for URL query parameters. It confirms that the authors of the RFC expect that `a=` is valid, but doesn't say anything about whether it would in general be equivalent to `a`.